# Firestore cloud function trigger with wildcard path

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

We a schema-less model where I would like to trigger a cloud function when a document is added to a `defects` collection. The thing is that any `defect` can contain a group of new defects collection (recursive).

How can I setup a cloud function that triggers on any of the following documents is updates / created:

`problem/defects/{document}`

`problem/defects/{document}/defects/{document}`

`problem/defects/{document}/defects/{document}/defects/{document}`

`problem/defects/{document}/defects/{document}/defects/{document}/defects/{document}`

and so on...

Comment: should it not be possible with a collectionGroup?

Comment: Can you trigger a cloud function with a collectionGroup?

Comment: sorry, yes it does not support. I thought you could just have a trigger with problem/defects/{wildcard}/ and the it would trigger for all writes within. The documentation says it is not possible :(

Comment: I sadly came to the same conclusion before posting this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Functions triggers do not allow wildcards that span more than one name of collection or document ID.  If you need a function to fire on any number of paths, you will need to define them each separately, but each function can share a common implementation, like this:

```
functions.firestore.document("coll1/doc").onCreate(snapshot => {
    return common(snapshot)
})

functions.firestore.document("coll2/doc").onCreate(snapshot => {
    return common(snapshot)
})

function common(snapshot) {
    // figure out what to do with the snapshot here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand correctly I need to create a trigger for every possible path. But since the possibilities are endless that would be a challenge

Comment: Or look into another way of organizing your data, even if that means duplicating data somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

With firestore functions, you can use wildcard paths to trigger for every possible path. However, you will need to specify a trigger for each level of document (i.e. - depth=1, depth=2,depth=3, etc...). Here is mine that I wrote to handle up to 4 levels deep:

```js
const rootPath = '{collectionId}/{documentId}';
const child1Path = '{child1CollectionId}/{child1DocumentId}';
const child2Path = '{child2CollectionId}/{child2DocumentId}';
const child3Path = '{child3CollectionId}/{child3DocumentId}';

export const onCreateAuditRoot = functions.firestore
  .document(`${rootPath}`)
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    return await updateCreatedAt(snapshot);
  });

export const onCreateAuditChild1 = functions.firestore
  .document(`${rootPath}/${child1Path}`)
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    return await updateCreatedAt(snapshot);
  });

export const onCreateAuditChild2 = functions.firestore
  .document(`${rootPath}/${child1Path}/${child2Path}`)
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    return await updateCreatedAt(snapshot);
  });

export const onCreateAuditChild3 = functions.firestore
  .document(`${rootPath}/${child1Path}/${child2Path}/${child3Path}`)
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    return await updateCreatedAt(snapshot);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error, I looked at the logs in `firebase-debug.log` and I saw the following error:

`"description": "Expected value chat/{tenant}/{customerId} to match regular expression [^/]+/[^/]+(/[^/]+/[^/]+)*"`

If you look at the regex, it's asking for an even number of paths. I updated the path and it worked.