# Firebase Functions Deploy: Error 3 - The Request has errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use 2 `wildcards` :

```
functions.firestore
    .document('establishments/{establishmentId}/payment/payments/{paymentId}')
```

and getting the

> "Error 3: The Request has errors".

However when using only 1 the function works normally:

```
functions.firestore
    .document('establishments/{establishmentId}')
```

Complete function code:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
    .document('establishments/{establishmentId}/payment/payments/{paymentId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        return secondaryApp.firestore()
            .collection("myCollection").doc("myDocument")
            .update(change.after.data());
    })
```

`--debug` log:

> [2021 - 07 - 13T16: 35: 32.864Z] << < HTTP RESPONSE BODY {
> "error": {
> "code":400, "message": "The request has errors", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "details": [{
> "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest", "fieldViolations": [{
> "field": "event_trigger", "description": "Expected value establishments/{establishmentId}/payment/payments/{paymentId} to match regular expression [^/]+/[^/]+(/[^/]+/[^/]+)*"
> }]
> }]
> }
> }
> ⚠  functions: failed to update function projects/myProject/locations / us - central1 / functions / myFunction

Firestore:

```
 - establishments: collection
   - {establishmentId}: document
     - payment: map
       - payments: array
         - {paymentId}: map
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60411815/firestore-cloud-function-trigger-with-wildcard-path

Answer (score 4):

Confirm that the path ends on a document and that it follows the pattern `collection/document/collection/document/...` I'd guess the path is supposed to be `'establishments/{establishmentId}/payments/{paymentId}'`

Comment: I have added how is the Firestore. So it can't end with paymentId once it's a map? Is there any way to get when update one specific ```payment```?

Comment: Ah I understand your situation more fully now. Unfortunately, I do not know how to achieve what you're attempting. Best of luck, I'm eager to see the solution as well!